# Is there an alternative to Microsoft Code Contracts static analysis?

Tags: visual-studio

I am very impressed with the [Microsoft Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).

Unfortunately the static analysis is only available in Visual Studio 2008 Team System and Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

We are happily using Visual Studio 2008 Professional (***without*** MSDN). Upgrading our Visual Studio license from pro to premium is way to expensive.

Is there a good alternative?

Comment: Looking for paid alternatives or free ones?

Comment: I don't mind forking out a few dollars. We are with six devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [MSDN Ultimate Offer for Devs](http://blogs.msdn.com/jonbox/archive/2009/10/22/the-ultimate-offer.aspx). It's not cheap, but it's *a lot* less expensive than 2008 Team Suite. Then you can use Visual Studio 2010 from now on with Code Contracts. :)

Also, Code Contracts is different from [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx), where the latter is what everyone is going to think you're talking about when you say "static code analysis."

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the following tools to help with my code analysis needs:

[CodeIt.Right](http://submain.com/products/codeit.right.aspx) can be used as an analysis tool.
[FxCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis) quite extensive and thorough and also free
[CAT tool 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0178e2ef-9da8-445e-9348-c93f24cc9f9d&displaylang=en) is a simple tool to help identify security flaws in managed code.

Concerning code contracts, take a look at [DevLabs portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/default.aspx) and click on the "Projects" link to link you to the Code Contracts project available for Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

The compiler that comes with the platform SDK has static analysis for free.
`cl /analyze`. You can configure your IDE to use it.